# Tag "survailence" should be "surveillance"

Tags: discussion, tags

Can tag names be edited? I didn't see a way to change it, I hope it's possible...

(The SE system is really bad at allowing users to report small problems like this: I can't suggest a tag synonym, this is not really a question, and I'm told that it does not meet our quality standards. Let's see if this extra text makes it happy).

Answer (score 2):

Done!  I had to merge <kbd>survailence</kbd> onto [<kbd>surveillance</kbd>](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveillance), which seems to have the effect of renaming it.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!

Comment: @MBaz You're welcome!!